# Are Loki's Horns Functional Or Decorative?

Tags: marvel, comics, loki

FYI: I'm most interested in the comics here and not anything in the TV/MCU versions.

Are the horns on Loki's helmet functional in any way?
Or are they purely decorative?

e.g. has he ever killed someone in battle with them?

Comment: In the MCU they're mostly decorative but someone is killed by a pair in _Loki_. I'll not answer with it if you're solely after comics information though.

Comment: In Ragnarok as well iirc - doesn't he stab somebody with them on the bridge battle?

Comment: I'd prefer a comics answer. You can add a footnote with an MCU example to it but I don't want a purely MCU answer.

Comment: It's tied to Loki being the biological son of Laufey, the ruler of the Frost Giants. In the Marvel Comics Universe, the Frost Giants wear helmets with horns.

Comment: @opticyclic - In case you're wondering why this question still has no answers, the problem is that "Has X ever happened?" type questions are easy to answer if someone happens to know of an instance where X _did_ happen. But if no one knows of such an instance, then unless someone has seen all 500 or so of Loki's comicbook appearances, the most they can really say is "Not that I know of", which isn't the type of answer we like to post around here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've probably seen the majority of Loki's appearances, and I know of no instances where he's used his horns as a weapon in the comics. It's hard to see why he would, since he can conjure up swords out of thin air in the comics. But I cannot guarantee that it has _never_ happened.